# How to save Mail attachment

Tags: pantheon-mail

I can't seem to find any way to save e-mail attachments from the Mail application. I have tried drag and drop to the desktop, but that does not seem possible. I do not see any command or icon that indicates how to save an attachment. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll achieve what you want by right click-ing on the attachement -> Save As...

[image: save as...]

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have enough reputation to add a comment to pop's answer, but still believe it belongs to the question, i put it in a new answer.

I have that dialog, but it seems that in the file save dialog that then comes up, i have no submit button and therefore cannot confirm the file destination.

[image]

I actually have the same problem when i save something from firefox. So it probably is not a mail problem only.

## Update: Answer

So, it seems that I had been having some overwrite settings on my gsettings. I might have had that since I was playing with some hidpi tool. The solution was for me to put:

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/DialogsUseHeader': <0>, 'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gtk/DecorationLayout': <'close:menu,maximize'>}"`

Cheers
Michael

Comment: Can't check now, but this doesn't seem to be the default theme, but a lighter version? Am I right? I used a theme that did exactly this: not displaying the bar which places the save button.

Comment: Have you updated your system? This seems like a bug which has been fixed a while ago.

Comment: Hi Eric, hi Jeroen, I do update regularly, and i get that issue irrespective of the theme i use.